# Background-image of an element over another element

Tags: html, css

The goal is to render a background-image of an "a" element over the div#slider element's backgroung-image.

First of all, here's the code:

```
<div id="top_bg">
    <div id="top">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link onegfdgdfg gd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slider">
</div>
```

jFiddle link contains my attempt on this: http://jsfiddle.net/zorza/drBBC/11/

I tried with absolute positioning of an "a" element inside a relative "li", which enables me a way to give it z-index, so it can appear over the #slider. It almost works, but requires for "li" to have constant width to position "a" inside it, which results in a bad way when the inner text is wider than the constant width (see first menu item).

What I'd like to get is an "a" element to set it's own width depending on an inside text and to get rid of a constant width of a "li" element, so the gaps between menu items will be even.

The second way I came up with was to slice #slider background into two graphics and place one of them (the one with the height of an arrow) inside the #top div background-image. This way an "a" element doesn't need to be positioned absolutely. But this solution isn't elegant at all an makes all sort of troubles when there is need to change the image.

Answer (score 2):

```
#top-bg{
    background-image:url('yourImage.png');
}
```

That will work. No need for div#background.

Edit try this:

```
a:hover :after{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    content:'';
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#333333;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:49%;
}
```

I think that should work. Without adding the image and without positioning new elements and repositioning the anchors

Comment: And you could do the same with your logo if you wanted. @zorza

Comment: It would require to structure and position the whole header of my site from the begining, which I'd like to avoid. Page's structure is slightly more complicated than a jFiddle example (real site: http://interclick2.home.pl/fiddle/1/index.php). Isn't there a way to do this whithin the existing markup?

Comment: Well for starters I know `z-index` doesn't work with JS fiddle. I'm not totally sure what you want to achieve. You want the image positioned under the `a` elements yes?

Comment: Yes, I want "a" element's background image (arrow) to appear over the div#slider element's background image, but without having to position "a" element absolutely (without z-index).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. You can see the effect it creates here: http://interclick2.home.pl/fiddle/3/ . When you delete the #slider_bg_x element with FireBug, you can see the arrow displaying in the same place no matter which "a" you hover on. And it's color is not what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, for width of an item to be all the same size

```
li, a {
display: /*block or inline-block depending on the layout you were after*/
}
```

and for an automatic width to a

```
a {
width: auto;
}
```